# Build Qt project with VS C++ Compiler 15.0 with C++17 to use WinRT APIs

Tags: c++, qt, uwp, windows-10, c++-winrt

I would like to use libraries available via WinRT API (like [these](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/)) from my UWP application created using Qt 5.9.2 for UWP 64bit (MSVC 2017). I got Visual Studio Build Tool 2017 v15.5.7 installed on my machine. Windows 10 is my OS.

Now, I have set up a kit as presented below.

[image: UWP Kit setup]

Then, in `.pro` file, I have added:

```
SOURCES += main.cpp

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/cppwinrt/10.0.16299.0/
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/cppwinrt/10.0.16299.0/
```

I got `cppwinrt` from [GitHub rep](https://github.com/Microsoft/cppwinrt).

I just added some lines in `main.cpp` to test proper compilation:

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <winrt/Windows.Devices.WiFi.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    WiFiAdapter wiFiAdapter;

    return a.exec();
}
```

After running `qmake` and `build`, I am getting this error:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.12.25827\include\optional(15): fatal error C1189: #error:  class template optional is only available with C++17.

[Windows documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/what-s-new-for-visual-cpp-in-visual-studio#c-compiler) clearly states that since v15.3 (once again, I have 15.5.7) C++ compiler accepts the `/std:c++17` flag. I have tried to pass it by adding one of these lines to `.pro` file:

```
CONFIG += c++1z
# Or
QMAKE_CXXFLAG=/std:c++17
```

None of them helped.....

This is the detailed build command run by compiler:

```
cl -c -nologo -FS -FS -Zc:rvalueCast -Zc:inline -Zc:strictStrings -Zc:throwingNew -Zc:referenceBinding -Zi -MDd -GR -W3 -w34100 -w34189 -w44996 -w44456 -w44457 -w44458 -wd4577 -wd4467 -EHsc /Fddebug\uwp-test.vc.pdb -DUNICODE -DWIN32 -DQT_LARGEFILE_SUPPORT -DQ_BYTE_ORDER=Q_LITTLE_ENDIAN -DWINAPI_FAMILY=WINAPI_FAMILY_PC_APP -DWINAPI_PARTITION_PHONE_APP=1 -DX64 -D__X64__ -D__x64__ -DQT_DEPRECATED_WARNINGS -DQT_CORE_LIB -I..\uwp-test -I. -I..\ne-patient-app-libraries\cppwinrt\10.0.16299.0 -I..\..\..\..\Qt\5.9.2\winrt_x64_msvc2017\include -I..\..\..\..\Qt\5.9.2\winrt_x64_msvc2017\include\QtCore -Idebug -I..\..\..\..\Qt\5.9.2\winrt_x64_msvc2017\mkspecs\winrt-x64-msvc2017 -Fodebug\ @C:\Users\NEUROE~2\AppData\Local\Temp\main.obj.11672.15.jom
```

What am I missing? What could solve the problem? Thank you!

Comment: C++/WinRT only requires /std:c++17, not /std:c++latest. I don't know Qt's build system well enough to figure out why that option isn't being passed along to cl.exe.

Answer (score 7):

You want `QMAKE_CXXFLAGS *= /std:c++17` - i.e. `_CXXFLAGS` not `_CXXFLAG`

The `*=` means add it if it's not there already.